# Class I created runs ok in dialogs set up code, but crashes when I call new inside actionPerformed method

Tags: java

I have a class, called `cDbcExchange`  that acts as an interface between my code and sqllight.

I'm using it to fill in list boxes of a jcombo box.
When I use it to fill in the intal values on the creation code it works fine.

When I try to create it within the `actionPerformed` method it crashes, I get following message

```
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The dialog could

```
.....
......
        // the class works fine outside of
        //  actionPerformed methed
        mDbcExchange2.close();

        ctrExchange.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 String sel = ctrExchange.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 ctrCur.removeAllItems();            

                 test++;
                 // CRASHES HERE WHEN i TRY TO CREATE THE OBJECT
                 cDbcExchange mDbcExchange= new cDbcExchange();

                 // the actionPerformed method                  
                 mDbcExchange.open();
                 DefaultListModel<String> names = mDbcExchange.getAllMarkets(sel);
                int size=names.getSize();
                String r;
                int b=0;
                for(b=0; b<size; b++);                      
                {
                    r=names.get(b);
                    ctrCur.addItem(r);                              
                }

                mDbcExchange.close();
                test++;
            }
        });


        pack();
        show();
      }
```

database class that is causing the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a debug point to the line above where the crash occurs..the start the application on debug mode ..then proceed step forward when the execution reach the debug point..you can see for your self the reason for the crash.(the object instantiation might be null..i am guessing)